# Fluent NHibernate and log4net

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, log4net

Although there are lots of questions and answer on this topic, I wasn't able to find an answer to my problem. I've configured log4net for NHibernate as described here: http://nhibernate.hibernatingrhinos.com/19/how-to-configure-log4net-for-use-with-nhibernate

The only difference being I configured log4net for use with a trace appender:

```
<appender name="trace" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender, log4net">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %p %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
....
    <logger name="NHibernate" additivity="false">
        <level value="ALL"/>
        <appender-ref ref="trace"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="NHibernate.SQL" additivity="false">
        <level value="ALL"/>
        <appender-ref ref="trace"/>
    </logger>
```

And presto, I get my NHibernate logging. However, I don't see any of the generated SQL queries, which is what I was hoping to see. I do get logging about opening and closing of sessions, commiting transactions etc. But nothing on the queries send to the database. Does anyone know what I'm overlooking?

I'm using Fluent NHibernate 1.2 which uses NHibernate 3.1. I've enabled `ShowSql()` in the configuration.

Comment: Try removing the `ShowSql()` call from the Fluent NHibernate configuration.

Comment: @Pieter - when you enable ShowSql(), do you see it in the VS output window, at least?  That works for me with FNH 1.0.  Should allow you to see the generated SQL - but it won't be saved, of course.

Comment: With `ShowSql()` enabled, the queries don't show up in the VS output window. Removing `ShowSql()` still don't get displayed in the log4net logging.

Comment: Correction: I've removed `ShowSql()` and now logging does seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the AdoNetBatchSize to zero in your fluent NH configuration:

```
Fluently
  .Configure()
  .Database(...) 
  .AdoNetBatchSize(0)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't change the situation. Still no queries in the logging output.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `additivity="false"` from both of the appenders.  Either that or use a different appender for `NHibernate.SQL`.  Setting them both to false doesn't really make sense in this instance.

If you want to separate the sql queries from the regular nhibernate logging then this does make sense **IF** you are using different appenders.

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.Additivity.html